# limit the size of the video 90-120 Using Flutter Video_trimer 0.5.2 package ... any suggestion?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I implemented the above Package (video_trimer 0.5.2) its stable with my current dart SDK and the trimer is working fine but the question is how i can limit the size of the video from 90-120 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

In [video_trimmer package](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer) you get the option to define the maximum video length. For example using this code `maxVideoLength: Duration(seconds: 120),` in the `TrimEditor` widget of in your code will make the video maximum duration to 120 seconds.

Further I suggest you to look at the [example project over github](https://github.com/sbis04/video_trimmer/tree/master/example/lib) and [documentation of the package](https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer) it will help you a lot in understanding the parameters of the package like what you can do with the package.